# Proof with a family of function

Tags: analysis

I have to prove that
$$f_a(x)=\ln x^2 +\frac{a}{x}$$
has no zeros if for $a>0$ it holds that $a\cdot e>2$.

I tried to find the zeros but I came to no result.

Comment: What did you try? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is not defined at $0$. If $f$ is defined on $(0, \infty)$ we can argue as follows:

$f'(x)=\frac  2 x-\frac  a {x^{2}}$ is positive for $x >\frac a  2$ and negative for $x <\frac  a  2$. Hence $f$ has  a minimum at $x =\frac a 2$. The minimum value is $2 \ln (\frac a 2)+2$ and this is positive if $ae >2$. Hence $f(x) >0$ for all $x$ if $ae >2$.

On $(-\infty, 0)$ the function $f$ vanishes at some point whatever $a$ is.

Comment: In fact, the proposition is incorrect when allowing negative $x$, as $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f_a(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f_a(x)=+\infty$ and $f_a(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for the comment. I have edited may answer.